# Remove directory on Uninstall of previous version

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, wix

I am using WIX installer to install application.The installer will remove existing two application before installation.The log file for that application is written and because of that log file,the log file contained folder is not deleted during the existing removal process.I need the wix installer to remove that junk folder during the installation of new application.

I tried this

```
<Component Id="deletejunk" Guid="GUID">
    <util:RemoveFolderEx Id="RemoveiDocDir" On="uninstall" Property="iDocDir" />
</Component>
```

It is not working for me.How to do this.

Comment: How are the two existing applications removed?  Are they MSI's being removed via FindRelatedProducts/RemoveExistingProducts or are they non-MSI's with custom actions calling out to uninstall commands?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter MSI's remove existing product via RemoveExistingProducts.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I have just used the regular (non-Util) based options...

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
  <Component Id="C__deleteJunk" Guid="{GUID}">
    <RemoveFile Id="__deleteJunkFiles" Name="*.*" On="uninstall"/>
    <RemoveFolder Id="__deleteJunkFolders" On="uninstall" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

This will clear all the files out of the folder, then it will delete the folder itself.  Give that a try.

Comment: I need to remove that existing application folder during the installation of new MSI's.That junk logs folder belongs to Old product.

Comment: Joe's approach should work.  But I question whether the installer should remove the logs in the first place as this is user data and the application is still installed.  If the application created the log it should remove it or archive it on next run when it realizes it's a newer version.